# Outcome of Needham-Schroeder protocol

Tags: cryptography

I am studying [Needham-Schroeder protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Needham%E2%80%93Schroeder_protocol) in my course subject and I understood it well, but there is a homework problem which is asking, "what is the outcome of Needham-Schroeder protocol?"

According to me, its outcome is a security session between Alice and Bob for communication and kdc is responsible for that security session. Is my answer is correct or is this question is about anything else?

Comment: I think your answer is in the top section of the wiki article on the topic

Comment: And do not give any weight to my name being any kind of authority on this particular protocol :)